# Function with ggplot: Specific selection parameters for dynamic plots

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am quite new in R and I have some algorithmic understanding problem.

I have a function called `country_function()` which can plot a bar plot graph.
The input data is "export00" so `country_function(export00)` is working well.

But I would like to add one paramater `t` in the function to create a data selection.

My data frame is quite simple:

```
   Country          Number

 1 Portugal         100000       
 2 Poland           200000       
 3 Israel           300000 
 4 South Africa     400000
 5 Austria          500000
```

I would like "t" to be the number of countries I want to see, and the rest will go under the category "Other".

So `country_function(export00, 2)` will show the 2 countries with the largest number (Austria and South Africa) and the rest will be "Other" (and other is the sum of the numbers).

For the moment, My code is using ifelse to select countries under a certain number ("ifelse(Number < 400000..."). So it is simple to input t a replace the number by t. but for the new code i dont know what to modify.

```
country_function <- function(export00) {

  country = export00 %>%
    filter(Number> 100000000) %>%
    mutate(Country = ifelse(Number< 400000000, "Other", Country)) %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    summarise(Number= sum(Number))

  p_country = country %>%
    arrange(Number) %>%
    mutate(Country = factor(Country, levels = Country)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = Number, label = Number, fill = Number)) +
    geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, hjust = "bottom", size = 2)

  return(p_country)
}
```

To sum up, I have a plot working with a number of countries I decide to have by selecting the min number and the rest is Other but I would like to select the number of country I want to see in my chart and the rest to be Other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
country_function <- function(export00, n) {

  country = export00 %>%
    arrange(Number) %>%
    mutate(Country = ifelse(row_number() >= n, as.character(Country), "Other")) %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    summarise(Number= sum(Number))

  p_country = country %>%
    arrange(Number) %>%
    mutate(Country = factor(Country, levels = Country)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = Number, label = Number, fill = Number)) +
    geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, hjust = "bottom", size = 2) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")

  return(p_country)
}
```

And to call the function and draw the chart:

```
graph <- country_function(export00,3)
graph
```